# From a collection, get a new collection based on condition. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have have this query. `events = eventswhere("starts_at <= ?", 3.months.ago)` which does what I want. Now with `events` I'm trying to call this. `events.where("ticket_types.present?")` but that doesn't get a new collection... What am I doing wrong? and what should my query look like?

Comment: If `ticket_types` is boolean you can do `events.where("tickets = ?", ticket_types.present?)`, because `ticket_types.present?` will give you `true` or `false`

Comment: What is `ticket_types`? Is it a column on the `events` table? Another relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want:

```
events.where("ticket_types <> ''")
```

For ActiveRecord > 4.0, you can also use `not`

```
events.where.not(ticket_types: '')
```